# How can one use the 'as' keyword in gremlin python?

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlinpython

When attempting to translate a query I wrote and tested in the Gremlin CLI to gremlin-python, I'm encountering `unexpected token 'as'` errors on my `.as('foo')` expressions. How can one use the Gremlin `as` keyword when using gremlin-python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Gremlin steps conflict with Python reserved words the step gets suffixed with an underscore, so for `as()` you would instead do `as_()`. A full listing of all the steps can be found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-python-differences), but currently they are:

**Steps** - `and_()`, `as_()`, `from_()`, `is_()`, `in_()`, `not_()`, `or_()`, `with_()`

**Tokens** - `Scope.global_`